# jquery ui modal dialog does not submit

Tags: jquery, user-interface, modal-dialog, form-submit

**My Aim** - User enters ClientName into autocomplete and selects ClientName. On selection, Apply button gets enabled.

On Apply button click, submit ClientName and ClientId to different PHP page.

**My Problem** - All works Ok, but does not redirect/post to the page url in the form action.

Can anyone help, many thanks.

```
$(function() {
 $("#btnCancelId").button();
     $("#btnApplyId").button();
     $('#btnApplyId').attr('disabled', true);
 $("#btnAddId").button();
     $('#btnAddId').click(function() {$divDialog.dialog('open'); return false;});

     $('#txtClientName').bind('keyup', function() {
 $('#txtClientId').val('');
 $('#txtClientId').css({'background-color': '#FFC0C0'});
 $("#btnApplyId:eq(0)").addClass("ui-state-disabled").attr("disabled", true);
  });

    var $divDialog = $('#divDialog');
    $divDialog.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: 'Company name',
  buttons: [{
     id: 'btnCancelId',
     text: 'Cancel',
     click: function() {$divDialog.dialog('close');}
     },{
      id: 'btnApplyId',
      text: 'Apply',
      disabled: true,
      click: function() {
        $('#divDialog').submit();
    //    $divDialog.dialog('close');
     }
     }]
 });

    $("#txtClientName").autocomplete({
      source: "_ajcustlist.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
   $("#btnApplyId:eq(0)").removeClass("ui-state-disabled").attr("disabled", false);
            $('#txtClientId').val(ui.item.id);}
    });
});
```

The Html code is -

```
<div id="divDialog">
  <form id="client_form" name="client_form" method="post" action="editinv.php">
   <input type="text" id="txtClientName" name="txtClientName" />
   <input type='text' id='txtClientId' name='txtClientId' style='display:none'/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a little hint, use input type="hidden" on ur second input instead of styling it invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event in your dialog action button is wrong. It's currently trying to submit a div (`$('#divDialog')`) instead of the form (`$('#client_form')`) within the div.

Change:

```
click: function() {
    $('#divDialog').submit();
    //    $divDialog.dialog('close');
}}]
```

to:

```
click: function() {
    $('#client_form').submit();
    //    $divDialog.dialog('close');
}}]
```

Comment: You're a star j08691, with an eagle eye. Submits Ok now. Thank you so much.